# What driver for M1015 for Solaris 11 Express

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, drivers

For Solaris 11 Express, what driver is supposed to be used? 
The M1015 is essentially a LSI 9240-8i

From 
http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9240-8i.aspx
The only driver for Solaris is a old 32bit driver?

I'd like to Flash it also, but can't seem to figure out which util to use.. The linux one from IBM screams for libraries that aren't included in the libraries section.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to use the new mr_sas (6Gbit/s) instead of the old mega_sas driver.

You can use scanpci to find out the vendor/device ID and add them with update_drv / add_drv so the correct driver gets attached. Check /etc/driver_aliases.